# Queuing Theory - Limited Population

Tags: stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I'm trying to understand the arrival rate of a queue model having a limited population size of $M$. Now the notes given to us from our lecturer state that the arrival rate is:

$$\lambda_n = \begin{cases} (M-n)\lambda,& 0\leqslant n<M\\ 0,& n\geqslant M\end{cases} $$

- $M$ = Total number of customers.
- $n$ = State number

Can someone please give me a formal or intuitive definition of this? Because I don't really understand how this holds. I searched online but haven't found any concrete definition about this, also I do not own any books regarding this study unit. Thanks.

Comment: If each customer arrives independently according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ and $n$ customers have arrived, then there are $M-n$ customers remaining to arrive. It follows from closure under superposition that the arrival process is then Poisson with rate $(M-n)\lambda$.

Comment: A single customer arriving according to a Poisson process is not well defined. I guess the intention is that any customer who is not in the queue arrives according to an exponential random variable, and then the total rate is given by the sum of rates. (Were the notes about a closed network?)